# Days left to specifc date in php / Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to get a simple "XX days left" for a custom post time I'm working with (jobs). I've tried to find the answer everywhere but nothing adapts well, changed my code 1000 times following examples on internet but I couldn't solve.

My code looks like this :

```
<?php
$today = date('d/m/Y');
$today = strtotime($today);
$finish = get_field('todate');
$finish = strtotime($finish);
//diference
$diff = $finish - $today;
$daysleft=floor($diff/(60*60*24));
echo "$daysleft days left";
?>
```

on $finish the get_field ('todate') returns the date dd/mm/yyyy

Anyone who can help me please?

Thanks!

Comment: You could just do `$today = time()` and skip the pointless "take unix time stamp, format into string, then parse back into the original unix timestamp it was 2 lines of code ago".

Comment: @dqhendricks the idea of echoing $daysleft is to show how many days left to the end date. $today gets the time today and finish returns the finish them, the strtotime was to have a number to make the difference from. I didn't know that dd/mm/yyyy was not supported.

Comment: @dqhendricks I managed to solve this, the code was 99% correct, I had to fix dates to american type (mm/dd) it does not work with european dates (dd/mm). The person on the answer 1 helped to solve it. I kind of hate this because I wanted to display the value of that same field but I will not able to because date format will be wrong, so I will have to have 2 inputs for the user (the publication finish date and the finish date in european format) thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is the arrangement of the d/m/Y (it should be m/d/Y) in your $today and $finish variables (for a listing of valid date formats that work with strtotime, visit the [PHP Date Format](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php) page):

```
<?php    
    $today = date('m/d/Y');
    $today = strtotime($today);
    $finish = get_field('todate');
    $finish = strtotime($finish);
    //difference
    $diff = $finish - $today;

    $daysleft=floor($diff/(60*60*24));
    echo "$daysleft days left";
?>
```

Tested and works, assuming the $finish date is entered as m/d/yyyy (not as d/m/yyyy)

Comment: Checking this cale, I was using dd/mm/yyyy because on my country the dates are set like that and I was displaying that field value in another place, that's what I wanted to keep the dd/mm/yyyy
I will try this and let you know, thanks!!!

Comment: Thanks - I figured that out while you were commenting, so I added the reference to the PHP documentation about date formats that work with strtotime.  Check them out to see which format might work best for you.

Comment: You might try using 30-6-2008 as the date format (from the [PHP Date Format Documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php))

Comment: If I set the finish date to 02/24/2012 the result displayed is "-251 days left" One thing, if I echo the $finish before strtotime I get the date correctly displayed, but if I echo the strtotime it doesn't show anything...weird.

Comment: Ok Cale, thanks for your help, I will use the dashed date instead slashes, let's see what happens

Comment: Changed the date to slashes using american format and still having a crazy number as result...

Answer (score 1):

`strtotime` will only parse a date in day-month-year format if the values are separated by dots, tabs, or dashes.  See [Date Formats](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php).

If you have PHP 5.2 or greater, you can use the following function to get total days:

```
<?php

$today = date('m/d/Y');
$today = new DateTime($today);

$finish = get_field('todate');  // MAKE SURE THIS IS m/d/Y or Y/m/d
$finish = new DateTime($finish);

//diference
$diff = $finish->diff($today);
$daysleft = $diff->format('%a'); // %a modifier means total days

echo "$daysleft days left\n";
```

This takes into account DST and leap years.

Comment: Thanks drew, I managed to solve this by changing the date format to american date format. It's working good now.

Comment: much better solution!

Answer (score 0):

How about this function?

```
 function DayDifference($start, $end) {
  $start = strtotime($start);
  $end = strtotime($end);
  $difference = $end - $start;
  return round($difference / 86400);
}
echo DayDifference("2012-02-10", "2012-02-20").' days left';
```